# Average of input prompt numbers

Tags: javascript, loops, average

I am having an issue with getting the average of the numbers that are inputted through a prompt window. I need to display the numbers like i have so far, but I can't seem to get them to add together to get the average.

here is my code so far.

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
function show_prompt() {
    i = 0;
    do {
        var number = prompt("Please Enter a Number");
        var number = parseInt(number);
        i++;

        document.write("Number: " + number);
        document.write("<br>");

    }
    while (i < 5);
}
show_prompt();
var avrg = number + number + number + number + number
document.write('Average of scores : ' + avrg);     
</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use an `array`, and examine `scope`.

Comment: What is "number" in the line ...  var avrg = number + number + number + number + number   ? That variable is not declared at that level. I only see a variable with the same name inside a function, not outside.

Comment: A variable can always only refer to a *single* value. You should learn about [**arrays**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object). Also, to get the average of a series of values, you have to divide the sum by the number of values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to move calculation inside function. Also you can do it simplier:

```js
function show_prompt() {
  var i = 0;
  var sum = 0;//declare a variable to keep the sum of numbers
  do {
    var number = prompt("Please Enter a Number");
    sum += parseInt(number); //sum the numbers here
    i++;

    document.write("Number: " + number);
    document.write("<br>");

  }
  while (i < 5);

  document.write('Average of scores : ' + sum / i);//use the sum of the numbers divide by the the numbers the user enters
}
show_prompt();
```

Tried to comment your old code with the mistakes:

```js
function show_prompt() {
    i = 0;
    do {
        //there is no need to declare number twice
        //also you don't sum somewhere the numbers you get from the user
        var number = prompt("Please Enter a Number");
        var number = parseInt(number);
        i++;

        document.write("Number: " + number);
        document.write("<br>");

    }
    while (i < 5);
}
show_prompt();
//number is out of scope of function show_prompt so is undefined
var avrg = number + number + number + number + number
//to get an avg you have to divide the sum by the number
document.write('Average of scores : ' + avrg);
```

Comment: There we go! Unfortunately you are not explaining what was the problem with the OP's code. *"You have to move calculation inside function."* is only one part of the problem. You changed a lot more than that.

Comment: OP tried to calculate the avrg out of the function. But variable `number` is undefined.

Comment: Yes, but that's not the only problem. There is no need to be concise, feel free to explain the changes properly.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I am fairly new at javascript so I was quite lost. This not only helped but worked perfectly, thank you again.

Comment: @FelixKling tried to comment old code with the mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Notice your var number is scoped within show_prompt(), it is not visible outside of it.

You need to have your show_prompt function not loop, and return the number, and have another function that calls show_prompt multiple times, takes the returns and calculate the average..  Also, your code is just calculating the sum, not the average

I'm not going to show you the exact code, but here's the idea

```
calc_average:
  var sum=0;
  loop 5 times:
    sum = sum + show_prompt();
  average = sum/5;

show_prompt:
  var number = prompt('blah blah');
  return number
```